# Find date from image/text

Tags: python, regex, datefinder

I have dates like this and I need regex to find these types of dates

```
   12-23-2019
   29 10 2019
   1:2:2018
   9/04/2019
   22.07.2019
```

here's what I did
first I removed all spaces from the text and here's what it looks like

```
   12-23-2019291020191:02:2018
```

and this is my regex

```
    re.findall(r'((\d{1,2})([.\/-])(\d{2}|\w{3,9})([.\/-])(\d{4}))',new_text)
```

it can find 12-23-2019 , 9/04/2019 , 22.07.2019 but cannot find 29 10 2019 and 1:02:2018

Comment: I think you can use the regex and find the date from the text.

Comment: @DhruvRajkotia Dates come in a lot of formats and some dates have words for months like  'jan,may,february,sepetember' , how to make regex for that?

Comment: here is the regex to find the months from the query.

^(?:Jan(?:uary)?|Feb(?:ruary)?|Mar(?:ch)?|Apr(?:il)?|May|June?|July?|Aug(?:ust)?|Sep(?:tember)?|Oct(?:ober)?|Nov(?:ember)?|Dec(?:ember)?)$

Comment: @WiktorStribiżew I tried to use regex to remove useless text but i am stuck at it fo days . Could you guide to me to a correct path

Comment: @DhruvRajkotia Thanks I'll try this

Comment: It is impossible to guide you since you just posted a dump of a file with no requirements set.

Comment: @WiktorStribiżew I have updated my question. Hope u understood where I am stuck at

Comment: Why have you removed the spaces? Keep them then apply: `\b\d{1,2}[\s:./-](\d{2}|\w{3,9})[\s:./-]\d{4}\b`

Comment: @Toto some dates have more than 1 spaces between them when that happens this is useless

Comment: So what is the problem, have you tried my regex, with `findall`

Comment: @Toto yes I am using findall

Comment: @Toto I applied your regex but that doesnt work either

Comment: `[x.group() for x in re.finditer(r'(?<!\d)\d{1,2}([.:/ -])(?:\d{1,2}|\w{3,})\1\d{4}(?!\d)', text)]`

Comment: @WiktorStribiżew Thanks a lot for the help!!!:)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You may use

```
(?<!\d)\d{1,2}([.:/ -])(?:\d{1,2}|\w{3,})\1\d{4}(?!\d)
```

See the [regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/XbDBZN/1)

**Details**

- `(?<!\d)` - no digit right before
- `\d{1,2}` - 1 or 2 digits
- `([.:/ -])` - a dot, colon, slash, space or hyphen (captured in Group 1)
- `(?:\d{1,2}|\w{3,})` - 1 or 2 digits or 3 or more word chars
- `\1` - same value as in Group 1
- `\d{4}` - four digits
- `(?!\d)` - no digit allowed right after

[Python sample usage](https://ideone.com/MEorit):

```
import re
text = 'Aaaa 12-23-2019, bddd   29 10 2019 <===   1:2:2018'
pattern = r'(?<!\d)\d{1,2}([.:/ -])(?:\d{1,2}|\w{3,})\1\d{4}(?!\d)'
results = [x.group() for x in re.finditer(pattern, text)]
print(results) # => ['12-23-2019', '29 10 2019', '1:2:2018']
```

Comment: I am extracting this text from images and sometimes there are more than one space in between the date. The answer you gave solves the rest of all problems

Comment: @KevinKurien I assumed the delimiter must be the same between the day and month and month and year, you may use `([.:/-]|\s+)` instead of `([.:/ -])`, and replace `\1` with the same pattern if you do not need to make sure the delimiter is the same.

Comment: the delimiter are the same and thats not the problem.The problem comes here ```12-23-  2019``` if there are more than 1 space then this does not work

Comment: @KevinKurien But you may use `[.:/\s-]+...[.:/\s-]+`, for example. Or `\s*[.:/-]\s*`. Or, `r'(?<!\d)\d{1,2}\s*([.:/ -])\s*(?:\d{1,2}|\w{3,})\s*\1\s*\d{4}(?!\d)'`. If needed, remove spaces from the matches as a post-processing step.

Comment: Thanks got it now. Thanks for the help:))